# Invalid Command 'DirectoryIndex'

Tags: apache, .htaccess, httpd.conf

I've got a fresh install of Apache 2.4 running, installed via homebrew. Everything seems to be working at the document root, localhost displays my sample html page and info.php is rendered fine. When I try to access one of my dev sites within the root I'm getting 500 Internal Server Error and see this message in the apache error log: `Invalid command 'DirectoryIndex', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration`. This appears to come from a directoryIndex declaration within my `.htaccess` file for the site. Removing it gets rid of the error but then the site displays as a directory index rather than trying to render the actual index.php file.

My httpd configuration looks like this

```
DocumentRoot "/Path/To/My/Doc/Root"
<Directory "Path/To/My/Doc/Root">
    #
    # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
    # or any combination of:
    #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
    #
    # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
    # doesn't give it to you.
    #
    # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options
    # for more information.
    #
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews

    #
    # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
    AllowOverride All
    #
    # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
    #
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I'm assuming the problem is within the httpd.conf file, but haven't had any luck figuring out what the actual cause is. As far as I can tell all the modules that should be enabled are, and the config file passes syntax validation. Any suggestions on how to get this figured out would be greatly appreciated, I'm banging my head on the desk over here.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure that mod_dir Loaded in `conf.modules.d/00-base.conf` file.

```
LoadModule dir_module modules/mod_dir.so
```

Comment: This seems to have been the culprit and my Macbook didn't read the change until I did a full system reboot. Restarting just Apache/httpd didn't do it for whatever reason.